# RxJava Android sequence print data

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm learning RxJava in Android.

**I have:**

```
Observable<Country> getCountries(){} // returns Countries
Observable<City> getCapital(int countryId){} // returns capital by country id
```

**I want:**

Print all country names returned by getCountries(). Then print capital name of each country from getCapital() method, except country with id=1. This all should be in one chain.

For example:

```
private Observable<Country> getCountries(){
    return Observable.just(
            new Country(0, "Luxemburg"),
            new Country(1, "Netherlands"),
            new Country(2, "Norway"),
            new Country(3, "India"),
            new Country(4, "Italy")
    );
}
private Observable<City> getCapital(int countryId){
    City city;
    switch (countryId){
        case 0: city = new City("Luxembrug");
            break;
        case 1: city = new City("Amsterdam");
            break;
        case 2: city = new City("Oslo");
            break;
        case 3: city = new City("Delhi");
            break;
        case 4: city = new City("Rome");
            break;
        default:
            city = new City("");
            break;
    }
    return Observable.just(city);
}


getCountries()
      .doOnNext(country -> Log.d("TAG", "Country: id="+country.getId()+" name="+country.getName()))
      .filter(country -> country.getId()!=1)
      .flatMap(country -> getCapital(country.getId()))
      .subscribe(city -> Log.d("TAG", "City: "+city.getName()));
```

What I want to get:

```
D: Country: id=0 name=Luxemburg
D: Country: id=1 name=Netherlands
D: Country: id=2 name=Norway
D: Country: id=3 name=India
D: Country: id=4 name=Italy
D: City: Amsterdam
D: City: Oslo
D: City: Delhi
D: City: Rome
```

What I get:

```
D: Country: id=0 name=Luxemburg
D: Country: id=1 name=Netherlands
D: City: Amsterdam
D: Country: id=2 name=Norway
D: City: Oslo
D: Country: id=3 name=India
D: City: Delhi
D: Country: id=4 name=Italy
D: City: Rome
```

How can I achieve this?

I should at first get all countries, print it and after then get capitals for this countries. But I don't understand how can I do this in one chain..

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the `getCountries()` and `getCapital(int countryId)` methods you can achieve it like this:

**RxJava 1x:**

```
    getCountries()
            .toList()
            .doOnNext(countries -> {
                for (Country country : countries) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Country: id=" + country.getId() + " name=" + country.getName());
                }
            })
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .filter(country -> country.getId() != 1)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Country, Observable<City>>() {
                @Override public Observable<City> call(Country country) {
                    return getCapital(country.getId());
                }
            })
            .subscribe(city -> Log.d("TAG", "City: " + city.getName()));
```

**RxJava 2x:**

```
    getCountries()
            .toList()
            .doOnSuccess(countries -> {
                for (Country country : countries) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Country: id=" + country.getId() + " name=" + country.getName());
                }
            })
            .toObservable()
            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(country -> country.getId() != 1)
            .flatMap(new Function<Country, ObservableSource<City>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<City> apply(@NonNull Country country) throws Exception {
                    return getCapital(country.getId());
                }
            })
            .subscribe(city -> Log.d("TAG", "City: " + city.getName()));
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response! But didn't work( Android Studio emphasize .doOnNext() by red color. And yes, I can't change methods signatures getCountries and getCapital(), I can change only method body.

Comment: This gives you exactly what you want but I used `io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0` I think you are using rxjava2 correct?

Comment: Yes, I use rxJava2. Is it better to try to use rxjava 1?

Comment: No better use newest version. With rxjava2 some of interfaces changed. I'll update the answer according to rxjava2

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you so much!! I should learn Rx more deeper. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you. Cheers